# mysql query based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a number of records where a search must only give a unique result based on  'valid from' and 'company' fields.

Here is an example of 4 records:

```
RECORD NO.  COMPANY        VALID_FROM  VALID_TO    VALUE   
1           BANCO CENTRAL  10/11/11    31/12/11  123.45
2           BANCO CENTRAL  20/11/11    31/12/11  120.34
3           EXTERIOR BANK  20/11/11    31/12/11  115.45
4           BANCO CENTRAL  25/11/11    31/12/11  115.45
```

Based on current date, I need to show only one of the resuLts 'per company'.
For example, if today is 26/11/11, the query would show records 3 and 4 (record 4 for company Banco Central, having a later 'valid from' date, replaces previous records (1 and 2). Record for Exterior Bank, being the only one, will show as well.

If today was 15/11/11, then it should show the first record (since the valid from value of record 2,3 and 4 is in the future)

If today was 20/11/11, then it will show record 2 and 3

if anyone can show me what the SQL query should look like will be much appreciated

Comment: This is a coomonly asked question. Click on the [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql) tag or at the links on the right, under the **Related** header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to a subquery:

```
select
    *
from
    banks b1
    inner join (select company, max(fromdate) as maxdate from banks where fromdate <= now()) b2 on
        b1.company = b2.company
        and b1.fromdate = b2.maxdate
```